# Immutable Django models

Tags: django, django-models, immutability

I want to save a new object whenever any model change is done instead of updating the current version.

For example, let's take a basic scenario where I have two model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    version = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    version = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

I have created a new Question object. 
Let call it Q1(pk=1) which have 3 answers attached to it A1(pk=1), A2(pk=2) and A3(pk=3).

Now when add a new answer A4(pk=4) to Q1(pk=1). It creates a new version of Q1(pk=2) and appends A4(pk=4) to it.

So that I can still access the previous version of Q1.

Comment: you can use [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal to catch the infrmation baout the object right before it is saved, and save new one and `return` so the original object was never saved

Comment: add this answers as a manytomanyfield in question, so that u can add all answers to a single question as list

Comment: You may want to first check existing model versionning apps: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/versioning/ (not sure there's something matching your needs here but...)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have checked django-reversions. Problem with that was objects were not immutable. Upon saving changes existing objects were getting updated instead of creating new object.